# Java Sqlitte передача аргументов в запрос

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

```
public static void changeNumber(String name, String surname, String newNumber) {
```

Обьясните почему так не работает:

```
try {
    String query = "UPDATE applicants SET phone_number= "+newNumber+" " +
    "WHERE first_name= "+name+" ";
```

"SQL error or missing database (no such column: Joseph)"

A так работает:

```
try {
    String query = "UPDATE applicants SET phone_number= "+newNumber+" " +
    "WHERE first_name= 'Joseph' ";
```

Причем phone_number видит в обоих случаях

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в первом примере Вы подставляете строковое значение без одинарных кавычек. В результате в предложении `WHERE` СУБД воспринимает это значение, как имя столбца.

P.S. Вообще формировать SQL запрос методом конкатенации, это bad practice. Лучше используйте парматрические запросы. Это сразу избавит от очень многих проблем.